# Html 5 Canvas Particle effect

Tags: html, animation, jquery-animate, core-animation, effects

hey guys I need guidance to recreate a wonder full effect which I saw in a website 
[Fifty-five.com](http://www.fifty-five.com/) . After the pre-load is over you will see the company's logo in a canvas.

I have have been successful in creating the particle in a canvas but what math goes into linking the particles to create a mesh like structure on mouse over the canvas ?

Comment: It's hard to assess the rules they're using just by observing the behaviour for a few minutes. However, the starting point would be some basic trigonometry (pythagoras) to assess which particles are within a defined distance of the current cursor point. After that it's simply a case of drawing lines between the current points of those particles within the range.

Comment: I think part of the effect is that as the particles decay some of the connections are orphaned.

Comment: Also.. the code's all there for you to see unminified.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet i read the code but it went over my head so needed help in making me understand the logic. I tried to map the function points but lost it mid way through !!

Answer (score 1):

I have found this http://cssdeck.com/labs/html5-canvas-particles-web-matrix Maybe you can add some mouse interactivity. Please show here the final result.

NOTE: I am not expert in this thing.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at particles.js:

http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

Their home page has a similar effect to that used on the Fifty-five.com site you mention.

You can enable "line_linked" to link the particles.

I hope this helps.